# How to specify Type Hint for Parameters for Custom Classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types, type-hinting

Let's say that I have created a class defined below, and I have called methods on it:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = []

    def add_friend(self, new_friend: Student):
        self.friends.append(new_friend)

student1 = Student("Brian")
student2 = Student("Kate")
student1.add_friend(student2)
```

The method `add_friend` has a parameter called `new_friend`, which is a `Student` object. How do I use type hints to specify that? I assumed that you just have to simply enter the name of the class, like `new_friend: Student` but it does not work. When I run it, I get a `NameError: name 'Student' is not defined`. I also tried `new_friend: __main__.Student`, but it gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), use the string name of the class for forward references:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = []

    def add_friend(self, new_friend: 'Student'):
        self.friends.append(new_friend)
```

Comment: This is correct.
When using type hints, forward-references and self-references are going to occur, and when they do, simply put quotes around the name of the class.